# Powershell - Unepxected Argument in SQL Script

Tags: powershell, sqlcmd

I am trying to compile a sql procedure script in a database that has some pattern/ string within enclosed in double quotes. I get an error when compiling this object using sqlcmd. This is the query I use in Powershell.

```
$query = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($_.FullName)
$result = SQLCMD -S $FullDBServer -E -I -Q $query -d $Database
```

this is the sql script I created to mimic my scenario. The value has to be stored with double quotes in the db.

```
SELECT '"hi"'
```

This is the error I see.

```
SQLCMD : Sqlcmd: 'hi"'
+ $result = SQLCMD -S $FullDBServer -E -I -Q $query -d $Database
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (Sqlcmd: 'hi"':String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
" -d local': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.
```

I have tried replacing the query in ps with escape characters, here-string. Doesn't help. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is more of a SQLCMD question than PowerShell.   Is "local" really the full name of the database?

Comment: no it will have the actual database name. I just used local as a dummy text. Issue is when my sql script has a text that needs to be stored with double quotes into the db and yes I execute it with sqlcmd in powershell.

Comment: `SELECT '\"hi\"'` in your file where `$query` is read from?

Comment: nope..did not work..same error.


    SQLCMD : Sqlcmd: 'hi\'': Unexpected argument. Enter '-?' for help.

Comment: Double up the quotes. SELECT '""hi""'.

Comment: nah. That din work too. I tried various combinations using this command.

$result = SQLCMD -S "<server instance>" -E -I -Q 'SELECT '""hi""'' -d "<db name>"
write-host $result

Comment: Another failed attempt.
PS Z:\2016_09_Bundle> $query =  @'
SELECT '"hi"'
'@
write-host $query
$result = SQLCMD -S "<server name>" -E -I -Q $query -d "<dbname>"
write-host $result
SELECT '"hi"'
Msg 1038,Level 15,State 4,Server ,Line 1 An object or column name is missing or empty.For SELECT INTO statements,verify each column has a name.For other statements, look for empty alias names.Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.Msg 105,Level 15,State 1,Server ,Line 1 Unclosed quotation mark after the character string''.